# Forming paper bags that can 'trap' 3D regions of max surface area

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry

An existence question based on ['Trapping' 3D regions with sheets of paper](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/347122/trapping-3d-regions-with-sheets-of-paper).

Given a sheet of paper S that is a planar convex region, one tries to form a 'closed bag' that contains a connected 3D region (could be non-convex) of *maximum surface area* within it. One can fold/wrinkle the paper and sew/glue at the edges but not stretch or tear-reglue.

**Question:** Is there any convex S such that there exists some connected 3D region with finite volume and same surface area as S that can be trapped in a bag formed by S?

If S is non-convex, it is easy to find cases where S can contain 3D regions with same surface area as the area of S itself - eg: a cross shaped sheet can neatly trap a cube with same surface area. However, for any convex S, the connected non-degenerate 3D region with max surface area it can trap *might* necessarily be non-convex (the only possible exception: S is a very long and very thin strip- and it winds many times around a 3D region it traps) or have strictly less surface area than the area of S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if $S$ is convex, then you can form what is called in
[*Geometric Folding Algorithms*](http://www.gfalop.org/) (p. 382)
a *perimeter-halving* as follows.
Pick any point $x$ on $\partial S$, and another point $y \in \partial S$ half
the perimeter away. Now glue the two perimeter halves together along
$\partial S$, with neither gaps nor overlap.

By Alexandrov's Gluing Theorem, this always produces a convex body
in $\mathbb{R}^3$
(a "connected non-degenerate 3D region").
If $S$ is a convex polygon, the result is a convex
polyhedron. (There are degenerate cases, such as choosing the diagonal endpoints
of a square $S$, that result in doubly covered convex polygons, but
one can avoid such degeneracies by moving $x$ and $y$.)

So this is like your example of the cube: the perimeter-halved convex shape
has surface area equal to the area of $S$.
This answers your question in a stronger form:

> "**Question**: Is there any convex S such that ...?"

This holds for *every* convex $S$.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed quite nice results: "for every convex polygon, every P-having folding gives a convex polyhedron"  and "infinitely many polyhedra can be made from any convex polygon". Hope you could clarify if *deciding* whether a given convex polyhedron can be so realized from some convex polygon(s) is also done.

Comment: @NandakumarR: That's a good question, essentially: Characterize all the convex polyhedra that can be achieved by perimeter-halving some convex polygon. This remains open (as far as I am aware), only settled when restricted to squares and equilateral triangles.

Comment: Thank you. One would guess that if a given polyhedron can be got via perimeter-halving from some convex polygon, the same polyhedron could be got by the same method from an infinity of mutually non-congruent convex polygons with same area. But is that a known thing?

Comment: @NandakumarR: I don't think that is "a known thing." But I need to think about this...

Comment: Just two remarks on the characterization of which convex polyhedra $\mathcal{P}$ can be achieved by perimeter-halving a convex polygon $P$. (1) $\mathcal{P}$ must have two "sharp" vertices, each with curvature $\ge \pi$ (deriving from the fold points $x$ and $y$). (2) This shows that none of the Platonic solids can result from perimeter halving, except possibly the regular tetrahedron. And I can exclude the tetrahedron by an ad hoc argument. [I don't know why mathcal is not working, at least not for me...]

Comment: [Ignore the remark about mathcal---Fixed now.]

Comment: Since more questions have come up, I would wait and look forward to more results on this subject to emerge. Just adding one more bit: what could one say about folding a convex sheet S so that a convex polyhedron is obtained with its 'wall' everywhere *two layers thick* and with total surface area equal to half the area of S?

Comment: @NandakumarR: Another nice question!